# How to freeze my jframe while program flow is happening in java

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, freeze

So I have a little puzzle made in Java, and let's just say there are buttons too on this puzzle which represent the puzzle. There is a solving method where a series of buttons are clicked to find a "solution", and it takes around 1 minute to solve it, so that is 1 minute of just clicking buttons

During this one minute, you notice the buttons being clicked by the computer as it changes color and shape during the program flow, I was wondering if there was a way to freeze the jframe before the solving() method is invoked and then unfreezes into the solution when the method is over?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused to exactly what you are asking, but I would suggest using this code to do what I believe you are asking for

```
private static boolean solveDone = false; //This should go in a the class, not here.

    //Create a new thread to handle processes while the JFrame is frozen
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            //Code to run while the JFrame is frozen should be put here.
            main.solveDone = true;
        }
    });

    //Sleep the program until the process is done.
    try{
        while(!solveDone) {
            Thread.sleep(10); //Interval in milliseconds to check if the puzzle is done goes here.
        }
        solveDone = false;
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //Code to run after solving goes here.
```

Now, this isn't the cleanest way to do this type of thing, but I believe it should work.

On the other hand, if you know exactly how much time it is going to take, you could do this.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            //Code to run while the JFrame is frozen should be put here.
        }
    });

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000); //The time in milliseconds to sleep the JFrame
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //Code to run after solving goes here.
```